# Solution to a linear algebra problem according ranks etc.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

I solved the following question, and I think I am correct, but I am not sure.

Given are three matrices, A,B and C. And $AB = C$.

Now the question is to fill in a couple of things. I will put these in bold.

1) The rows of C are linear combinations of the rows of ***B***.

I answered this because when you write it down, you can see this.

2)So, the rank of C is not bigger than the rank of ***B***

Explanation. If A = m*n, B=n*p C will be m*p. So the dimension of the column space can only be maximum p.

3) Because $B^TA^T=C^T$ the rank of C isn't bigger than the rank of ***A***. This is due to the fact that the columns of C are linear combinations of the ***columns*** of **A**

I think this is because, when you have a matrix C of m*p, m can be smaller then p or m can be bigger than p, When p is smaller than m, the amount of columns of C limits the rank. When p is bigger than m, the amount of rows limits the dimension of the column space and the rank.

Are all these explanations true, or did I make som major mistakes? What can I say more ?

Thank you for your help,

Kind regards

Thomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $A$ as a matrix of rows:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\\vdots\\a_m\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then, as matrix of rows,
$$
AB=\begin{bmatrix}a_1B\\a_2B\\\vdots\\a_mB\end{bmatrix}
$$
so you want to see that, for a row vector $y$, $yB$ is a linear combination of the rows of the rows of $B$; write $y=[y_1\ y_2\ \dots\ y_n]$, so, if
$$
B=\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\\vdots\\b_n\end{bmatrix}
$$
we have
$$
yB=y_1b_1+y_2b_2+\dots+y_nb_n
$$
which is a linear combination of the rows of $B$.

This clearly implies that the row rank of $C$ is less than or equal to the row rank of $B$, because the row space of $C$ is a subspace of the row space of $B$.

Similarly, the columns of $C$ are linear combinations of the columns of $A$, because you can apply the same reasoning to $C^T=B^TA^T$ and the rows of $C^T$ are linear combinations of the rows of $A^T$.

Therefore the column rank of $C$ is less than or equal to the column rank of $A$, because the column space of $C$ is a subspace of the column space of $A$.

Comment: So y1,y2,.... is representing a1,a2,.....?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, you can take $y$ as any row vector you want, including $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_m$.

Comment: $$
aB=a_1b_1+a_2b_2+\dots+a_nb_n
$$

Ok, then this is the same ? Than I understand it I think.

Comment: I can't see it for some reason...

Comment: @Thomas This is the second part: after showing how the rows of $C$ can be written as $a_kB$ ($k=1,2,\dots,n$), writing $B$ as a matrix of rows shows that each $a_kB$ is a linear combination of the rows of $B$.

Comment: Ok, I see it. Essentially, when you plug B written as rows into the equation of AB you get for row 1:

$a_1*B=a_1*b_1+a_1*b_2+a_1*b_m$

Is there a particular reason why you are proving this with the y?, for some reason it is confusing me. I don't know why.